# CS:GO server starting with only one player

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

For some reason my CS:GO game is starting when there is only one player, allowing bomb plants or time to run out and using up rounds. How do I make it so it only starts with 2 or more players?

Comment: What happens if a second palyer joins? The server should restart the match then

Comment: What game mode are you talking about and how often? if it's casual, then servers get spun up on demand, so you could just be first in and you don't have to wait for other players to join before the game can start.